# Golang: help understanding pointers, assignment, and unexpected behavior

Tags: pointers, go, variable-assignment, biginteger

So I am back with more beginner questions that I can not seem to wrap my head around. 
I was experimenting with the following code.

```
func main() {
start := time.Now()
var powers []*big.Int
for i := 1; i < 1000; i++ {
    I := big.NewInt(int64(i))
    I.Mul(I, I)
    powers = append(powers, I)
}
fmt.Println(powers)
fmt.Println(time.Since(start))
start = time.Now()
var seqDiffs []*big.Int
diff := new(big.Int)
for i, v := range powers {
    if i == len(powers)-2 {
        break
    }
    diff = v.Sub(powers[i+1], v)
    seqDiffs = append(seqDiffs, diff)
}
fmt.Println(seqDiffs)
fmt.Println(time.Since(start))
}
```

my intention was to assign the result of Sub() to diff in the following way

```
diff.Sub(powers[i+1], v)
```

however this results in seqDiffs's value being 1995 (the correct last value) repeated over and over. I know that this is likely because seqDiffs is just a list of pointers to the same memory address but what I dont understand is why the following works just fine

```
v.Sub(powers[i+1], v)
seqDiffs = append(seqDiffs, v)
```

this results in seqDiffs being a list of all the odd numbers from 3 to 1995 which is correct but isn't this essentially still a list of pointers to the same memory address as well? 
Also why is the following correct when it should also result in seqDiffs being a list of pointers to the same memory address as well?

```
diff = v.Sub(powers[i+1], v)
seqDiffs = append(seqDiffs, diff)
```

also I tried to do it the following way

```
diff := new(*big.Int)
for i, v := range powers {
if i == len(powers)-2 {
    break
}
diff.Sub(powers[i+1], v)
seqDiffs = append(seqDiffs, diff)
}
```

but received these errors from the ide:

```
*./sequentialPowers.go:26: calling method Sub with receiver diff (type **big.Int) requires explicit dereference
./sequentialPowers.go:27: cannot use diff (type **big.Int) as type *big.Int in append*
```

How would I make an "explicit" dereference?

Comment: For your last question, you've ended up with a pointer to a pointer. new() returns a pointer to something and inside new you've made it a pointer to a big.Int. So `diff := new(*big.Int)` makes diff a pointer to a pointer. This means it can't be used where you're trying to use it as it's expecting just a pointer to a big.Int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When debugging issues with pointers in Go, one way to understand what is going on is use `fmt.Printf` using `%p` to print the memory address of variables of interest.

In regards to your first question as to why when appending the results of `diff.Sub(powers[i+1], v)` to your slice of `*big.Int` results in a slice where every index is the same value - you are updating the value at the memory address `diff` is assigned to and appending a copy of that pointer to the slice. Thus all values in the slice are pointers to the same value.

Printing the memory address of `diff` will show this to be the case. After populating your slice - doing something like the following:

```
for _, val := range seqDiffs {
    fmt.Printf("%p\n", val) // when i ran this - it printed 0xc4200b7d40 every iteration
}
```

In your second example, the the value `v` is pointer to a `big.Int` at a different address. You are assigning the the result of `v.Sub(..)` to `diff`, which updates the underlying address diff is pointing to. So when you append `diff` to your slice, you are appending a copy of of a pointer at a unique address. Using `fmt.Printf` you can see this like so -

```
var seqDiffs []*big.Int
diff := new(big.Int)
for i, v := range powers {
    if i == len(powers)-2 {
        break
    }
    diff = v.Sub(powers[i+1], v)
    fmt.Printf("%p\n", diff) // 1st iteration 0xc4200109e0, 2nd 0xc420010a00, 3rd 0xc420010a20, etc
    seqDiffs = append(seqDiffs, diff)
}
```

Regarding your second question - using the `new` keyword in Go allocates memory of the specified type but does not initialize it ([check the docs](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#allocation_new)). A call to `new` in your case allocates a type of pointer to a pointer to a `big.Int` (`**big.Int`), thus the compiler error saying you cannot use this type in your call to `append`.

To explicitly dereference `diff` in order to call the `Sub` on it, you would have to modify your code to the following:

```
(*diff).Sub(powers[i+1], v)
```

In Go, a selector expression dereferences pointers to structs for you, but in this case you are calling a method on a pointer to a pointer, thus you have to *explicitly* dereference it.

A very informative read on calling methods on structs (selector expressions) in Go can be found [here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors)

And to add it to the slice

```
seqDiffs = append(seqDiffs, *diff)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response; it is very helpful. I run into problems every time I use the math/big package. It will result in many minutes of stamping out type errors until I finally have code that results in the expected output but leaves me feeling, and my coding looking, like I went around the block three times to get to the corner. Is there an accepted and simple way to consistently use these methods that will result in a variable with a unique memory address?

Comment: Moving the initialization of diff, diff := new(big.Int) , inside the loop works beautifully with diff.Sub(powers[i+1], v). I assume this is because this creates a variable diff at a unique memory address for every iteration?

Comment: @StephenAdams - glad to be of help - moving `diff` inside the loop is a good solution to your problem